# Where can I report an issue or feature idea for the Data API Builder?

Tags: data-api-builder

I have been using the Data API Builder for some time and like it. However, from time to time I find things that seem like a bug or have ideas I would like to share with the team to make the builder better. Where is the right place to submit bugs for the Data API Builder or post ideas for future features?

Comment: Customer support questions really should be posted directly to their respective product-specific channels. See [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Data API Builder is an open-source project on GitHub. If the bug or feature you have is with the engine itself, you can use the `issues` area of the repository.

https://github.com/Azure/data-api-builder

The Data API Builder can be hosted in Static Web Apps (SWA) on Azure. If the bug or feature you have is related to SWA, you can use their CLI repository.

https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps-cli/issues